# How do I download the source for Alpine Linux packages

Tags: linux, alpine-linux

I'm trying to get the source packages for various Alpine packages that are installed on my images (for compliance reasons) and I'm having trouble tracking them down.

For instance, I have alpine-baselayout-3.1.2-r0 installed and I can see the [package details](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/alpine-baselayout) and it links to the git repo, but it's to the aports tree which has the APKBUILD file and things needed to build the apk files (and source packages) but not the package itself. I was also able to find the [APK package itself](http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/main/x86/alpine-baselayout-3.1.2-r0.apk), but searching that tree does not give a source package. And then looking at https://git.alpinelinux.org/alpine-baselayout/ I can see several older packages that appear to be source packages (but maybe just git tree snapshots), but nothing newer than 7 years.

So, how do I download the source packages for Alpine packages?

Comment: [aports - Main aports tree](https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/refs/)

Comment: aports is a single repo of the configuration that generates the apk packages (which are binary packages). Theres an intermediate step where the source files are generated, but unlike other Linux archives I can't find those source packages archived anywhere. So no, aports is not the answer.

Answer (score 5):

If anybody needs to download the source code for Alpine Linux packages, please follow this detailed [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509609/455592).

Just run `abuild fetch` in `/aports/main/alpine-baselayout`. `abuild fetch` creates the dir `src` (within the current directory).

So you can find the sources (or the links to the files) at `aports/main/alpine-baselayout/src`.
You could also change the destination of `src` with `export SRCDEST="/path/to/my/custom/src/destination"` before running `abuild fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem. I noticed that the APKBUILD file will state the path to the original source archive and patches used to build the apk package.

With the original source archive and the patches used to build that package in included aports, that gave me enough to define the apk package's source.